# How do I move the radio buttons down?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

My question is the following: What do I do (either in the HTML, CSS, or both) to move the radio buttons down? I want it so that the first radio button is in-line with the question and the following radio buttons are beneath the first i.e. listed in a 1,2,3 order going down.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="question">
    <label>At what time of day did it happen?</label>
</div>
<div class="answer">
    <input type="radio" id="morning"><label for="morning"> Morning</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="afternoon"><label for="afternoon"> Afternoon</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="evening"><label for="evening"> Evening</label>
</div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
.question {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    text-align: right;
}

.answer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 45%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional div `wrapper` class container and [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) properties `align-items:flex-start`, `justify-content: center` and  A little white space like `gap` properties in this case.

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.question {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    text-align: right;
}

.answer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="question">
    <label>At what time of day did it happen?</label>
</div>
<div class="answer">
    <input type="radio" id="morning"><label for="morning"> Morning</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="afternoon"><label for="afternoon"> Afternoon</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="evening"><label for="evening"> Evening</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just need to add `vertical-align: top;` to `.answer`'s CSS